# Insufficient privilege when running AWS Backup start_copy_job fumction

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-backup

I'm trying to start a copy job to copy RDS snapshot from one backup vault to another backup  vault in diferent region using lambda function but getting error with this message:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartCopyJob operation: Insufficient privileges to perform this action
```

function call is like this-

```
        result =conn.start_copy_job(RecoveryPointArn='my-arn',
            SourceBackupVaultName='my-vault',
            DestinationBackupVaultArn='my-dest-vault-arn',
            IamRoleArn='AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole')
```

Following permissions assigned to lambda role-

```
All resources   
Allow: backup:*
Allow: backup:CopyFromBackupVault
arn:aws:backup:*:*:backup-vault:*   
Allow: backup:DescribeBackupVault
Allow: backup:CopyIntoBackupVault
```

Could someone explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: The lambda function doesn't have the permission to perform `StartCopyJob`. Please share the lambda role.

Comment: As mentioned, the Lambda function itself needs permission to run `StartCopyJob`. The `AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole` isn't in play here until the AWS Backup job starts and AWS Backup assumes that role. The thing (Lambda in this case) triggering this backup job still needs permission to actually trigger the backup job.

Comment: Following  permission assigned to lambda-All resources 
Allow: backup:*
Allow: backup:CopyFromBackupVault
arn:aws:backup:*:*:backup-vault:* 
Allow: backup:DescribeBackupVault
Allow: backup:CopyIntoBackupVault

Comment: you don't have access policy on the back up vault?

Comment: source backup vault  has following  policies -{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow xxxx to copy into CrossAccountSource",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:root"
            },
            "Action": "backup:CopyIntoBackupVault",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Looking at this policy, I can see that `AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole` is not given the permission to act on it. In your backup vault you can add a permission to Allow role level access to a Backup vault. Then you edit the role with the one you mentioned  `AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole`

Comment: Thanks.I attached following policy to source vault but still getting the same error{
           "Sid": "statement ID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/service-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "backup:DescribeBackupVault",
                "backup:CopyFromBackupVault",
                "backup:StartBackupJob",
                "backup:StartCopyJob",
                "backup:ListRecoveryPointsByBackupVault"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }

Comment: ok.. What happens if you execute the lambda code just as a normal python script from your PC? Do you get the same issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have permission to run using cli

Comment: This is not about running the aws cli, it is about running the python script locally;

Comment: What I meant I don't have access to credentials to run.

Answer (score -1):

I need to provide full arn of role AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole
like

arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole

```
    result =conn.start_copy_job(RecoveryPointArn='my-arn',
        SourceBackupVaultName='my-vault',
        DestinationBackupVaultArn='my-dest-vault-arn',
        IamRoleArn='arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33712083)